# Showing the result of a query

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

I'm trying to build a query to get the numbers of rows that have the same data on a column (my column is ESTADO).

```
 var db = Database.Open("MyDB");
 var selectedData = db.Query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM graficos WHERE ESTADO='FECHADO'");

 var data = db.QueryValue(selectedData);
```

But when i try to run it gives the following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'WebMatrix.Data.Database.QueryValue(string, params object[])' has some invalid arguments

Line 51:      var data = db.QueryValue(selectedData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the query directly to the `QueryValue()` method.

```
var data = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM graficos WHERE ESTADO='FECHADO'");
```

Read [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.queryvalue(v=vs.111).aspx) for more information on how to use the `Database.QueryValue()` method.

Comment: Just one more thing (if you know it of course). What's the best way to put that value to a chart ?

Comment: I can't help you there, buddy